# Can any one explain to me what is the meaning of “Science of Stupid aired on the National Geographic Channel” and “ to hit your wits”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

Here is the Phrase which I am Reading

> There is absolutely no dearth of insane people, and their snaps clicked right in time by some people who are always ready with their cameras.
>
> The famous show, *Science of Stupid* aired on the National Geographic Channel exposed us to many such hilarious acts. So, we too tried to bring some of those pictures to hit your wits.

And Here I am having one question whether National Geographic channel slams the science of stupid show or the show slams National Geographic Channel.

I searched in Google for the meaning of air of someone or something means to express or to expose. Here in this context what does "Science of Stupid aired on the National Geographic Channel" mean?

And I didn't found any Idiom meaning of "to hit your wits" in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The show "The Science of Stupid" is apparently hilarious pictures and videos of crazy people doing stupid things.  It's hosted by the National Geographic Channel, which means they picked the name (probably because it's catchy).  It's not "slamming" anyone, except perhaps the people in the videos.

"Hit your wits" means "make you think".  It's not something we would ordinarily say, but rather something the writer of this made up because pairing two rhyming words sounds good.

Edit:  "To air" something has an additional meaning, "to broadcast or be televised".  So if you say "some program aired on some channel" it means it was broadcast on television.

Comment: Thank you for your answer now I understood the phrase clearly.